# Python connection to mysql error : unexpected indent

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python

I am new to Python.

Here is the code I have written to insert a row to a mysql table:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="me",          # your username
                     passwd="mepassword",  # your password
                     db="Database")   # name of the data base
 cursor = db.cursor()

f = '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %z]'
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(result[1], f)

sql = (
  "INSERT INTO Database.Table (Name, Time, Number, Size, Answer) "
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %d, %d,  %s)"
)
data = (result[0],now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),int (result[3]),int (result[4]),result[2])
cursor.execute(sql, data)
db.close()
```

But when I run this code I get the error:

```
File "myscript.py", line 40
    cursor = db.cursor()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I don't understand this error. How can this be a problem with the cursor definition? I use the default cursor definition. Or is this a problem with the mysql connection? Where is the problem?

Comment: This is simply whitespace error.  Python is whitespace sensitive.  There cannot be extra spaces such as leads the fifth line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="me", passwd="mepassword", db="Database")
cursor = db.cursor()

f = '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %z]'
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(result[1], f)

sql = ("INSERT INTO Database.Table (Name, Time, Number, Size, Answer) " "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %d, %d,  %s)")
data = (result[0],now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),int (result[3]),int (result[4]),result[2])
cursor.execute(sql, data)
db.close()
```

You had incorrect indents in your code.  In python we don't use `brackets {}`, 
instead we use `indents` for hierarchy.

Comment: Thank it work well now